# How to initialise a Numpy array of numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a `numpy array D` of dimensions `4x4`

I want a new numpy array based on an user defined value `v`

If `v=2`, the new numpy array should be `[D D]`.
If `v=3`, the new  numpy array should be `[D D D]`

How do i initialise such a numpy array as `numpy.zeros(v)` dont allow me to place arrays as elements?

Comment: Do you want the new array to be 2D or 3D? It's not quite clear what `[D D]` is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to take a 2D array and tile it `v` times in the first dimension? You can use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
# a 2D array
D = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)

print D
# [[0 1]
#  [2 3]]

# tile it 3 times in the first dimension
x = np.repeat(D[None, :], 3, axis=0)

print x.shape
# (3, 2, 2)

print x
# [[[0 1]
#   [2 3]]

#  [[0 1]
#   [2 3]]

#  [[0 1]
#   [2 3]]]
```

If you wanted the output to be kept two-dimensional, i.e. `(6, 2)`, you could omit the `[None, :]` indexing (see [this page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for more info on numpy's broadcasting rules).

```
print np.repeat(D, 3, axis=0)
# [[0 1]
#  [0 1]
#  [0 1]
#  [2 3]
#  [2 3]
#  [2 3]]
```

Another alternative is [`np.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html), which behaves slightly differently in that it will always tile over the last dimension:

```
print np.tile(D, 3)
# [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#  [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows:

```
import numpy as np
v = 3
x = np.array([np.zeros((4,4)) for _ in range(v)])

>>> print x
[[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, see if this works for you.

```
import numpy as np
v = raw_input('Enter: ')
```

To intialize the numpy array of arrays from user input (obviously can be whatever shape you're wanting here):

```
b = np.zeros(shape=(int(v),int(v)))
```

I know this isn't initializing a numpy array but since you mentioned wanting an array of [D D] if v was 2 for example, just thought I'd throw this in as another option as well.

```
new_array = []
for x in range(0, int(v)):
    new_array.append(D)
```

Comment: appending to numpy arrays is quite slow and something you should generally try to avoid doing

Comment: Which is why it wasn't my first answer, just an alternative.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read that more carefully - I just realised you weren't actually creating a numpy array at all, but rather a *list* of numpy arrays. You'd have to then convert the list to a numpy array, using `np.concatenate`, `np.vstack`, `np.hstack` etc. Either way, it's more efficient to use `np.tile` or `np.repeat` to get there in one call.